alembic upgrade head from within FastAPI using async sqlalchemy
I've been looking at this for a while and not having any luck.  If I run "alembic upgrade head" from the command line, it works great.  I would like to do that from within FastAPI so when it starts up, it upgrades the database schema.  So from lots of searching, I came up with this method:
async def run_migrations():
  alembic_cfg = Config("alembic.ini")
  url = str(engine.url)
  async with engine.begin() as conn:
    await conn.run_sync(alembic_cfg.set_main_option, "sqlalchemy.url", url)
    await conn.run_sync(command.upgrade, alembic_cfg, "head")

I call it during the FastAPI lifespan startup. It gives me this error:
TypeError: Config.set_main_option() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

I've also tried:
await conn.run_sync(alembic_cfg.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", url))

But that gives me:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Does run_sync not like the way I'm doing this? I'm not passing 4 arguments to set_main_option.  The value of url is correct because I printed it out to make sure.
Or is there an easier/better way of doing an upgrade to head from within fastapi?
Thanks

SQLAlchemy            2.0.32
uvicorn               0.30.6
fastapi               0.112.1
alembic               1.13.2


Probably the issue that you try to set the sqlalchemy.url in Alembic's Config object within the run_sync function. It should work if you update the code like this:
async def run_migrations():
    alembic_cfg = Config("alembic.ini")
    
    url = str(engine.url)
    alembic_cfg.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", url)
    
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(command.upgrade, alembic_cfg, "head")


Ahhh. Nice.  That got me past that error.  Now it's failing during the upgrade command with:
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'get_main_option'
Must be something with my async engine connection

Marking this as the right answer since it fixed my original issue.  I'm going to start a new thread for my other issue.
